# How to select an html element according to its child node attribute in css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For example, in the following snippet:

```
<tr>
 <td align="center">123</td>
 <td class="someclass">abc</td>
</tr>
```

I would like select all `<tr>` elements that have a `<td>` with the `class="someclass"`.

I am wondering if this is possible in css, without using javascript. Thanks.

Comment: Please define the snippet more clearly. `123 abc` isn't really a helpful example of your particular use case.

Answer (score 4):

What your asking for isn't possible. CSS reads left to right, meaning that you can't specify the parent element based on a childs attributes. You can do this in javascript but like you said you didn't want to use that.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="green">
       Some text
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <div class="red">
       Some Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
.box {
    color: blue;
} 

.box .green {
    color: green;
}

.box .red {
    color: red;
}
```

As you can see, you can select the parent element by itself but not based on a child's attributes.

Technically, you should always work outwards in. If you need a specific style to be applied on the parent you should add an extra class.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="box green">
    Some Text
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
.box.green {
    color: green;
}
```

You can see in the above CSS that you can "stack" the classes to select the proper element.

Hope this helps, if you have any questions just ask. I can post a javascript variation that would be able to select an element based on child element attributes if you open a new topic  for that.

Answer (score 0):

To select elements with a particular class:

```
.someclass{
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like select all elements that
>   has a with class attribute
>   "someclass".

If by selection you mean node selection that you can only use JavaScript.

### jQuery:

```
$(".someclass").doStuff();
```

But if by selection you mean CSS selection then:

### CSS:

`<element class="someclass">` can be selected using `.someclass` in CSS.